# Prolog - Dynamic predicate returning true even though asserta/1 is not yet executed

Tags: prolog

Here is the following whole code.

```
start:- main.
    
    main :-
        trace,
        write('Ruled Based Diagnostic System'),
        ask('Conduct Diagnosis in Emergency Mode? ', EmergencyMode), 
    
        not(   
            absent(EmergencyMode) ->  
                (   
                    Question = 'Does the patient have the following symptomp: ',
                    check(Question),
                    disease(Diseases),
                    format('The patient may have ~w', [Diseases]),
                    undo
                )
            
        ) 
            ->  
        
            (   
                write('Running in emergency mode!'),
                undo
            ).
        
    ask(Question, Symptomps) :-
        nl,
        format('~w~n', [Question]),
        read(Answer),
        
        (   
            member(Answer, [y,yes, 1]) ->
            (   
                write('Answer is Valid'), nl, asserta(present(Symptomps))
            );
        
            member(Answer, [n,no,0]) ->  
            (   
                write('Answer is Valid'), nl, asserta(absent(Symptomps))
            );
        
            ask(Question, Answer, Symptomps)
        ).
    
    ask(Question, Answer, Symptomps):- 
        format('Answer ~w is invalid', [Answer]),
        ask(Question, Symptomps).
    
    
    
    /* General Symtomps */
    check(Question):-
        check(Question, headache),
        check(Question, fever),
        check(Question, chills),
        check(Question, vomiting),
        check(Question, coughing).
    
    
    disease(influenza):- influenza, !.
    disease(measles):- measles, !.
    
    measles :-
        Q = 'Does the patient have the following symptomp: ',
        check(Q, fever),
        check(Q, coughing),
        check(Q, runny_nose),
        check(Q, conjunctivitis),
        check(Q, blotchy_rash_more_than_three_days).
    
    influenza :-
        Q = 'Does the patient have the following symptomp: ',
        check(Q, fever),
        check(Q, headache),
        
        (   
        check(Q, coughing);
        check(Q, runny_nose);
        check(Q, sore_throat);
        check(Q, muscle_pain)
        ).
    
    check(_, Symptomp) :-  
        present(Symptomp).
        
    check(_, Symptomp) :-
        absent(Symptomp).
         
    check(Q, Symptomp) :-   
        join_func(Q, Symptomp, Question),
        ask(Question, Symptomp).
        
        
    
    /* dynamic predicates */
    :- dynamic present/1.
    :- dynamic absent/1.
    
    /* utility functions*/
    join_func(ToJ1, ToJ2, Result) :-
        name(ToJ1, List1),
        name(ToJ2, List2),
        append(List1, List2, List3),
        name(Result, List3).
    
    
    undo :-
        retractall(present(_)),
        retractall(absent(_)).
```

Querying for *start.* starts the program as usual.
However, the problem is that after entering *n/no* in emergency mode, the rule *check* assumes that the dynamic `present/1` and `absent/1` is already true even though it is not yet asserted (which would mean its neither present nor absent, which leads to the program asking data from the user). This means that it automatically assumes that everything is fact or `true` concluding that the patient has an influenza without even giving the program a chance to actually ask for data.

I do not know much of prolog but I do know all of the basics in other languages such as java, c, or c++. A help would really be appreciated as this is my first time using a declarative language.

Answer (score 0):

First:

- Calling `trace` in an interactive program is bad. `trace` should be used interactively, on need.
- What is `undo`?
- You need to declare `absent/1` and `present/1` as dynamic, otherwise an error message will be presented.

```
:- dynamic(absent/1).
:- dynamic(present/1).
```

What happens:

After the call

```
ask('Conduct Diagnosis in Emergency Mode? ', EmergencyMode)
```

where `EmergencyMode` is an unbound variable (it has no defined value yet), we enter a switch statement. After entering `Yes` or `No` (invalid answers lead to a recursion and a re-ask), the Prolog database will contain

`present(_)`

or

`absent(_)`

respectively, because an assertion is made with `Symptomps` (sic - the correct spelling is `Symptoms`) an unbound variable. (`_` of course is the notation for an `anonymous variable`, to be used when we don't care about the name, only that it is different from any other variable in the same clause.)

Now we continue with

```
not(   
    absent(EmergencyMode) ->  
    (   
       ...
    )
) 
->  
(   
   write('Running in emergency mode!'),
   undo
).
```

(What is `undo` btw?)

The meaning is unclear (It think it is correct but it's the equivalent of logic sphagetti code) as the program will write "Running in emergency mode!" if

```
absent(EmergencyMode) ->  
(   
    ...
)
```

fails, and otherwise fail bacause the "else" part of the `->`, here left out, is `fail` by default.

However, in

```
absent(EmergencyMode) ->  
(   
    ...
)
```

The premiss `absent(EmergencyMode)` will succeed if `No` (no emergency mode) has been entered previously because `absent(_)` is in the Prolog database and will match any goal/query that looks like `absent(_)`.

Now we call

`check('Does the patient have the following symptomp: ')`

which starts off a conjunction with

`check('Does the patient have the following symptomp: ', headache)`

which fails, because the database contains no entry that might match the above: there is no fact or rule that applies.

So this fails immediately. So we are in the situation:

```
not(   
    absent(EmergencyMode) -> fail  
)
```

So the above goal succeeds, and so the program writes 'Running in emergency mode!'.

And indeed:

```
?- start.
Ruled Based Diagnostic System
Conduct Diagnosis in Emergency Mode? 
|: No.
Answer is Valid
Running in emergency mode!
true.
```

(The code may be based on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vM5I-E-TZm0 ?)

Comment: undo is just calling retractall(present(__)) and retractall(absent(__)). Also, the code is based on my lectures combined with youtube videos.